# What is the first SF story in UK/USA starring a non-western character?

Tags: history-of

In one of the introductions to a collection of his short stories, Asimov reminisced with his time with *Astounding Science Fiction*.

He commented that he always suspected that Campbell, the editor of *Astounding* thought of men in space as basically white men in space. Strange really, as SF, when it works well, is about investigating the human condition like all other great works of fiction. And it seems bizarre to ignore the human condition of everyone else on this Earth. (Perhaps not so bizarre when one contemplates the everyday racism of that era and which Asimov was far too circumspect to mention).

I'm curious as to what the first published science-fiction in either the UK or the USA that starred a non-western character in the role of the protagonist.

Obviously, aliens or robots don't count.

Comment: What does count?  I'm sure there are stories dating way back that just don't even bring up the geneology of the protagonist (or other characters).  Attribution of any characteristics is left to the reader.

Comment: @SteveV: if a character was named Brian one can assume, I think, that it is a white westerner. If for some reason the character was black, that would be so unusual that one would expect the author to comment on this. What's hard to understand as earliest? I mean, I don't think Jules Verne or HG Wells had any non-western characters.

Comment: The correct tag is history-of, not story-identification. Do not switch the tags again.

Comment: What I am saying is that most people understand identification  to mean "I have this specific thing in mind. What is it?"  With [tag:history-of] questions, you have no specific thing in mind. You want to understand the development of the genre. In fact, people usually do not really want the *name* of the work so much as the *year*.

Comment: @Adamant: What's with the *l'authorianiste* No? If you, Null, and TheLethalCarrot were interested in tagging clarity, then the obvious solution is to add a tag, *first-story-of*. Instead, you seem to be much more invested in pedantically enforcing tedious tagging rules. Like I said, *bureaucratic conformiste*.

Comment: @Mozibur-Ullah Anyone with sufficient reputation can add a tag. The problem is that in order to retag all the other questions, there would need to be consensus. So, some background here. People used to ask questions of the type "Are there any stories like this?" At the time (maybe not anymore?) those were considered "Too Broad."  So it was agreed that in order to keep them on-topic, people would be encouraged to ask "What is the first....?" questions instead, which, being very important to the history of the genre, naturally would get tagged with [tag:history-of].

Comment: In fact, there most certainly is a case for a [tag:first-of] tag, to be used in conjunction with [tag:history-of] but not with [tag:story-identification], given how many questions of this type we have. If that would be an acceptable resolution for you, we could try bringing up the case for it on the meta site. I cannot guarantee that everyone would agree (again, this is a community-run site with certain rules, not Facebook or something) but it could win if presented the right way. Otherwise, the question will just end up locked again, because tags do have to be used according to the guidelines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer because I am unable to find any text to quote.  That said, The [Encyclopedia of Science Fiction's](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com) [Race in SF page](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/race_in_sf) suggests Herrmann Lang's *The Air Battle* (1859).  (This being the earliest, of those listed, that seems to include overt SF elements, and that is [listed in the ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1063747).)

I found a short description of the book that says:

> The novel presents in short compass a remarkable portrait of a world several millennia hence, long after European civilization has been destroyed by floods and earthquakes and other Disasters; the peace-loving black rulers of the country of Sahara dominate Africa, and in a final battle with other powers utilize their great heavier-than-air machines – the first sf use of such devices as Weapons – to establish a beneficial world-wide Pax Aeronautica, which may be first instance of the use of air power in this sense.

[user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232305/what-is-the-first-sf-story-in-uk-usa-starring-a-non-western-character/232309?noredirect=1#comment636320_232309) found a much [longer review](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_fiction_the_Early_Years/KEZxhkG5eikC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=herrmann%20lang) in [*Science-Fiction, The Early Years*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_fiction_the_Early_Years/KEZxhkG5eikC?hl=en&gbpv=0) (page 420) on Google books.  While confirming that the 3 main characters are white, there is at least 1 major viewpoint character who is not:

> Subplots are concerned with the adventures of Jakadox, a
> Saharan [black] boy who speaks future Cockney.  He escapes captivity
> among the Madeirans, lands inadvertently on an island inhabited
> by blue-skinned savages who propose to burn him alive, then
> escapes to England, where he is instrumental in the downfall
> of the wicked Jonas.

Jakadox gets married at the end, which seems to confirm his status among the heroes of the book.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. It would be nice to know what the story and the characters were about. Too bad you haven't discovered anything you can quote.

Comment: @DavidW There's [This review on Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1241176655/ref=dp-kindle-redirect).  Reading it, I suspect this inspired Michael Moorcock for [_Warlord of the Air_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlord_of_the_Air).

Comment: Some further description here; not clear if protagonists are non-western, but appears that there are characters of importance with a range of ethnic backgrounds. https://devilofhistory.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/the-worst-proto-sf-novel-in-the-history-of-the-world/

Comment: @MoziburUllah Now that that's solved, I wonder what's the earliest non-western story (any genre) starring a western character? The earliest Asian story starring a non-Asian character?

Comment: @user14111: Well, why don't you ask it on the stack? It's not a question that interests me, otherwise I would have asked it

Comment: The review by John J. Pierce here says it shows 3 Britishers in 3 different countries: https://www.amazon.com/Air-Battle-Vision-Future-Hermann-Lang/dp/B003LPUMIQ. It might be that they are the stars.

Comment: @Jetpack Oh, that's a good find.  I agree that the review makes is sound like the protagonists are all British.  Now, what to do about this answer?

Comment: An honorable mention should go to "Prince Dakkar, son of the Hindu raja of Bundelkhand, and a descendant of the Muslim Sultan Fateh Ali Khan Tipu of the Kingdom of Mysore" aka Captain Nemo (introduced in 1870 in "20 000 Leagues", identified in 1875 in "Mysterious Island"), if only because the OP so angrily insisted that Jules Verne could not have non western characters (Verne is French of course, but then the OP brought him up himself).

Comment: You can read E. F. Bleiler's review of *The Air Battle* (in *Science-Fiction: The Early Years*) at Google Books: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_fiction_the_Early_Years/KEZxhkG5eikC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=hermann%20lang

Comment: If another example is needed, J. A. Mitchell's 1889 [*The Last American*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_American_(novel)), while 35 years later, has the advantage of having the full text available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/7485), and all the viewpoint characters are non-western, being Persians exploring the ruins of postapocalyptic America in the 30th century.

Comment: @Eike Pierstoff, I think you should add that as an answer.